# Advice on JavaScript library for visualizing Yahoo Pipe Output

Tags: javascript, json, visualization, yahoo, yahoo-pipes

I'm currently writing a JavaScript library. It is a project for school were I need to make it easier to visualize data from Yahoo Pipes. The data format is a JSON string, which can contain anything, but mostly contains a list of items, with different attributes for each item.
This approach is quite general and now I was wondering which functionality I could insert into this library. Also how I can deal with this general flow of data to make a usable library for all kinds of data..
The data from Yahoo Pipes can be news items (title, description, postdate, images, links,..) Yahoo Pipes also has functionality for parsing CSV files, so "data tables" are also possible.

Also I was thinking about the structure of the library, what the best way is to implement it.
In general the library needs to load in the data from the pipe (JSON string) and pass it to a visualization library like Google Chart or D3.js (formerly Protovis)

I would consider my Javascript skill level as 'Rookie' :)
Thanks for the replies, any advice is welcome!

Comment: Much like the data which you describe, your question is largely amorphous and vague. What are you asking?

Comment: The structure of the library and way of programming. If a should make it 'low-level' like JQuery for example, which has no interface. Is that possible? Or if I should make some kind of interface for more usability.

Comment: What do you mean by "interface?" In what way is jQuery "low-level?"

Comment: Like I mentioned, my knowledge of programming and JavaScript is not advanced. Sorry for the doubt, I meant "User Interface". If I should make a UI for handling the data, managing it and displaying it or if I can write the functionality without UI so it can be used by others.

Comment: Maybe I should better post my question in the programmer section of stackexchange.